# getview not called in CustomAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview, adapter

In class 1 I have a hashmap which I send to my CustomAdapter.

```
map.put("year", "Apple");    
map.put("make", "Mango");     
map.put("model", "Grape");    
map.put("style", "Orange");     
map.put("series", "Peach"); 

//link to my adapter
setListAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(DynamicLists.this, R.layout.row, map));
```

But in class 2 my MyCustomAdapter `getView` function is not getting called, can you help understand why ?

thanks

CODE

```
//class 1 
public class DynamicLists extends ListActivity { 

   //class 2 
   public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter { 
       String my_VALUES;
       public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                              HashMap<String, String> map) {

           String[][] array = new String[map.size()][2];
           int count = 0;
           String combined="";
           for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()){
               combined=""+entry.getKey()+""+entry.getValue();
               count++;
           }
           my_VALUES = combined;
       }

       @Override
       public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
           View row=convertView;

           if (row==null){
               LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
               row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
           }

          TextView label =(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.blocked);
          label.setText(my_VALUES);

          return row;         
       }

       @Override
       public int getCount() {
           return 0;
       }


       @Override
       public Object getItem(int position) {            
           return null;
       }


      @Override
      public long getItemId(int position) {
          return 0;
      }  
   }  //end of class 2 


   private static final String TAG = "Example";


   public static  HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(); 

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     //tie data to list, call constructor MyCustomAdapter 
     //populate the list. ArrayAdapter takes current class, layout and array
     map.put("year", "Apple");    
     map.put("make", "Mango");     
     map.put("model", "Grape");    
     map.put("style", "Orange");     
     map.put("series", "Peach"); 
     //link to my adapter
     setListAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(DynamicLists.this, R.layout.row, map));         

   }


   @Override
   protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
      //super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
      String selection = l.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
      Toast.makeText(this, selection, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();        
   }        

} //end of class 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
getCount()
```

How many items are in the data set represented by this Adapter.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html

```
 @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return size;// more than zero
    }
```

`getItem()` must return something

```
@Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return my_VALUES;// may be in your case
    }
```

Comment: do I need to declar size somewhere ?

Comment: its the no of element your map contains.

Comment: This is what I get in trace 04-04 15:01:59.264: WARN/Resources(2432): Converting to boolean: TypedValue{t=0x3/d=0x5da5 "res/anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator.xml" a=1 r=0x10a0004}
04-04 15:01:59.294: DEBUG/Example(11986): HELLO WORLD [series=Peach, model=Grape, year=Apple, style=Orange, make=Mango]
04-04 15:01:59.294: DEBUG/Example(11986): HELLO WORLD INSIDE ADAPTER [series=Peach, model=Grape, year=Apple, style=Orange, make=Mango]
nothing else seems to be happening

Answer (score 1):

Must declare Size. 
Your `GetCount()` function must declare size... Set the return to 1 and your list will be populated by one item.
So if you are passing in a cursor, just return `cursor.getCount();`

Soo... And you List will be populated Properly.

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
   return cursor.getCount();
}
```

In your case return the size of your map.